# Is there a good way to get from Levoča to Lviv?

Tags: planning, routes, ukraine, slovakia

Due to a change of plans, I'm now going to visit the Ukraine *after* I visit Slovakia.

Right now I'm looking at options for going from Levoča to Lviv. Rome2rio is not [showing](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Levo%C4%8Da/Lviv) any good options. I'm hoping that this is a deficiency in the rome2rio site<sup>1</sup> and not a lack of any really good transport options.

This is what I've found so far:

1. **By Train** (12 hr 22 min, with 3 hr 23 min transfer)

   - Levoča to Spišská Nová Ves (16 min, hourly)
   - Spišská Nová Ves to Košice (54 min, hourly)
   - Košice to Čierna nad Tisou (1hr 41 min, hourly
   - Čierna nad Tisou to Chop (37 min, 5x daily)
   - Chop/Чоп to Lviv (5hr 31 min, 4x daily)
2. **By Bus** (12 hrs 4 min, 3 hr transfer)

   - Levoča to Prešov (1 hr 19 min, 5x daily)
   - Prešov to Uzhhorod/Ужгород (3 hr 40 min, 1x daily)
   - Uzhhorod/Ужгород to Záhony/Захонь (22 min, 1x weekly - this is in Hungary?!)
   - Záhony/Захонь to Lviv (3hr 43 min, 1x weekly)

The bus route is horrifying. At this point I've started thinking it may be better to go back into Poland to Rzeszów or Przemyśl and go from there.

Is there a simpler (eg no more than two transfers) way to get from Levoča to Lviv? I'd rather not go back into Poland, and I'd also rather not hitchhike.

---

<sup>1</sup> I've run into other scenarios where rome2rio missed entire travel options because they don't have interfaces with particular bus companies, train operators, whatever.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, there is in fact a daily direct train from **Spišská Nová Ves** to **Lviv**:

[image]

Itinerary found using the fantastic [JizdniRady website](http://jizdnirady.idnes.cz/vlakyautobusy/spojeni/).

Comment: You are my hero for saving me from the five-train itinerary... Though how the direct train could take longer than the five-train combo is a bit puzzling.

Comment: It stops at every single village and also changes wheels at the border.

Comment: @JonathanReez If you happen to have an iPhone (or iOS device) I strongly recommend this application https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/cestovne-poriadky-cp/id1054934213 to you its in English, you can sometimes buy tickets right from the app (through web view), it shows where you are (calculating time, no GPS) etc. very nice app to use in Central Europe (just use Bus+Train, or Train setting - other settings are for public transport inside certain cities in Slovakia) it uses same data source as cp.sk (obviously), and that is same as idos.cz - JizdniRady.

Answer (score 5):

The [Маршруты](http://transport.marshruty.ru/) web site, which also has an [English-language interface](http://russticket.com), has timetables and tickets for the Russian public transport system.
A search for your route shows a bus that leave Levoča at the Poprad-Tatry station, with a change of bus in Mukacheve, which takes 5 hours and 19 minutes to arrive in Lviv, at a cost of 11.98 EUR

Comment: "a bus that leave Levoča at the Poprad-Tatry station" Poprad - Tatry is 30 km from Levoča, so you would also have to find a way to get there, which seems to take about 1 more hour.

Answer (score 4):

I was going with pretty much the same itinerary in August, and my intention was essentially the opposite, I wanted to visit Poland on my way :-) What I can say is that pretty much any public transportation between Presov and Rzeszow is dead, I had to hitchhike on that part. That's why I think your idea of going through Uzhhorod instead makes sense.

There are several buses a day from Kosice to Uzhhorod. Going from Uzhhorod to Lviv is absolutely easy, no need to visit Zahony. Lots of [trains](http://booking.uz.gov.ua/en/) and [blablacars](https://www.blablacar.com.ua/poshuk-poputnikiv/uzhgorod/lviv/#?fn=%D0%A3%D0%B6%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%2C%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&fc=48.6208%7C22.287883&fcc=UA&tn=%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2%2C%20%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&tc=49.839683%7C24.029717&tcc=UA&sort=trip_date&order=asc&limit=10&page=1) there. IMHO, to have some rest from the long trip it makes sense to sleep over in Uzhhorod, which is a nice town.