# Buses in the Balkans

Tags: buses, montenegro, balkans, albania, kosovo

I'm currently planning a trip through the Balkans, flying back home at the end of it from Dubrovnik. I've found good resources for pretty much everything, however, information (in English, at least) is tricky to come across.

My ideal itinerary is as follows (a night or two in each of the intermediate stops):

1. Pristina
2. Shkoder
3. Kotor
4. Dubrovnik

Rome2Rio makes some "interesting" suggestions, but there are lots of 13 hour, multi-country routes between cities that appear to be 2-4 hours drive from one another.

Does anyone know if there are better, local options (equivalent to marshrutki maybe?)?

Comment: I don't know why you're seeing the routes you're seeing, but if the cities are in different countries it could be that there is no international bus service on the direct route.  The solution in that case is to take a bus to the closest possible point and then walk or take a (normal) taxi to the border.  I've spent a good deal of time in Croatia and Bosnia and Herzegovina, and I have never come across anything like marshrutki there; I don't know about other Balkan countries.

Comment: [This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82572/rome2rio-alternative-for-the-balkans-eastern-europe) of mine might help you. Balkanviator.com and getbybus were the best resources I found, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Also there was a direct kotor-dubrovnik bus when I was there two years ago.

Answer (score 1):

[BusTicket4.me](https://busticket4.me/EN) will cover what you need for the routes that involve at least one city in Montenegro.

I'm not aware of any online search options for Pristina - Shkoder, but you'll find several forums with info of varying recency if you google the route.